# Too few arguments to function using pointer

Tags: c, pointers, terminal

I'm using C to get a terminal size. That function will be call in the main function. Then I'm hoping to run it again to check if either the terminal size has changed or remain the same. This time the function are called in other function which is run_menu. For additional info, the run menu are also called in the main function. I will explain more in the code. The errors are "too few arguments to function 'get_terminal_size'.

```
//this function is to get the terminal size
//my idea is to use pointer as it will be use again in other function
void get_terminal_size(int *x, int* y)
{
    int cols,lines;
    assert(x);
    assert(y);

    #ifdef TIOCGSIZE
    ioctl(0,TIOCGSIZE, &ts);
    lines = ts.ts_lines;
    cols = ts.ts_cols;

    #elif defined(TIOCGWINSZ)
    struct winsize ts;
    ioctl(0,TIOCGWINSZ, &ts);
    lines = ts.ws_row;
    cols = ts.ws_cols;

    #endif
    *x = cols;
    *y = lines;
}

//this function is to see either the size has changed or not
int change_terminal_size()
{
    int new_cols, new_lines;
    int x, y;
    get_terminal_size(&x, &y);

    #ifdef TIOCGSIZE
    ioctl(0,TIOCGSIZE, &ts);
    new_lines = ts.ts_lines;
    new_cols = ts.ts_cols;

    #elif defined(TIOCGWINSZ)
    struct winsize ts;
    ioctl(0,TIOCGWINSZ, &ts);
    new_lines = ts.ws_row;
    new_cols = ts.ws_cols;

    #endif
    log_debug("new lines=%d,new cols =%d",new_lines,new_cols);
    if((new_cols !=x)||(new_lines != y)){
    return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//this function is to run the menu.
static void run_menu()
{
  //bla bla bla with other declaration and function
  //i will not write it because its not related
    while(1){
        if (change_terminal_size()){
        log_debug("the terminal has change size");
        }
  //and it will continue with other things

 //this is the main function
 int main()
 {
  //again with other declaration and function not related
  get_terminal_size();
  run_menu();
  //continue on with other thing, then return 0     
 }
```

As you can see. I call the "get_terminal_size" function 2 times. Is it related to the problem that im having? As far as I know, if I'm using a pointer, then it shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: If your going to downvote it. At least leave a comment why you did so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a function which takes two parameters, but you are not using any parameters when you do it. You do use the correct number of parameters in `change_terminal_size`, which is why that function succeeds.

The good news, though, is that since `get_terminal_size` does not affect the outside world, you can replace `main` with:

```
int main()
{
  run_menu();
  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I think I got the point now. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In here:

```
//this is the main function
int main()
{
  get_terminal_size(); //<---Right here!
  run_menu();  
}
```

You don't pass any arguments to get_terminal_size.

get_terminal_size expects to be called with two arguments, thus the error "Too few arguments to function".

"Using a pointer" doesn't really have anything to do with it, nor does "Using a pointer" allow you to use the function from multiple places.  All the pointers (x and y) do is allow the function to change values outside of its scope.

Sidebar: you probably ought to have get_terminal_size return a value - in this case probably a struct with an X field and a Y field.  Functions that return values via side-effect are more difficult to reason about and more likely to contain bugs, although this particular example is probably fine since you're not mixing input arguments with output arguments.

Also your change_terminal_size() function looks pretty gnarly.  Where are you keeping track of the old terminal size so you can compare it to the new terminal size?

Answer (score 2):

`get_terminal_size(int*, int*)` is a function with two parameters of type `int*`. In order to call this function, you must pass it the appropriate number of arguments each with the correct type. In `main`, you call it with no arguments and your compiler complains, as it should.

The `main` function will need to pass some appropriate arguments - something like below:

```
 int main()
 {
  //again with other declaration and function not related
  int x = 0, y = 0;
  get_terminal_size(&x, &y); // &x and &y both have type int*
  run_menu();
  //continue on with other thing, then return 0     
 }
```